# Cannot modify property of object copied from ngrx state using two way binding with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have a component with a property

```
activeData: MyData;
```

In ngOnInit, I subscribe to activeData in the store, and make a copy of the object from the store using structuredClone() and assign it to the local property

```
this.store.select(selectActiveData).subscribe(state => this.activeData = structuredClone(state))
```

Now in my template, i'm trying to bind a select element to a property on this.activeData:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="activeData.someProp" (ngModelChange)="onSomePropChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

When the selected value changes, I get the error `Cannot assign to read only property 'someProp' of object '[Object Object]'`

However, if i instead use one way binding from component to view and modify activeData.someProp in onSomePropChange(), there is no error

i.e. in template:

```
<select [ngModel]="activeData.someProp" (ngModelChange)="onSomePropChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

in component:

```
onSomePropChange(value: string) {
   this.activeData.someProp = value;
}
```

I don't understand why the two-way binding with ngModel causes this error as im creating a clone of the object from the store and not mutating the state directly. I also don't understand why i'm able to modify the property on activeData from the component but not from the view.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? I have a feeling it may be because activeData is a complex nested object, but I thought structuredClone() should take care of that.

Comment: If state immutability is enabled, NGRX freezes the whole tree https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/main/modules/store/src/meta-reducers/immutability_reducer.ts but, as you said, `structuredClone` should take care of it. Can you prepare an example to reproduce the problem?